# Error when using fnAddData with data-order

Tags: datatables

I have a `datatable` which is originally populated server-side.  Users may interact with the datatable by adding row data in a modal-popup.  I recently added the data attribute `data-order=''` so that we can better handle date sorting.  Now, our call to `fnAddData` dies with either of the following errors:

> DataTables warning: table id=dtTable - Requested unknown parameter
>   '[object Object]' for row 3, column 0. For more information about this
>   error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

OR

> DataTables warning: table id=dtTable - Requested unknown parameter '1'
>   for row 6, column 1. For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/4

Simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/2yu7mLL3/

I checked out the support documentation on datatables.net but they don't address this specific issue.  How do you use *fnAddData* if you are also using **data-order**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try constructing `tr` node and use newer [`row.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) API method that accepts node as an argument.

For example:

```js
$("#btnAddRow").on("click", function() {    
   var newRow = ['4/4/2014', '<test> Name'];
   var newRowOrder = 999;
   var $row = 
      $('<tr><td data-name="ReadingDate" data-order="' + newRowOrder + '">' 
      + $('<div>').text(newRow[0]).html() 
      + '</td><td data-name="Name">' 
      + $('<div>').text(newRow[1]).html() 
      + '</td></tr>');

   $("#dtTable").DataTable().row.add($row).draw();
});
```

See [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/2yu7mLL3/8/) for code and demonstration.

I have [created an issue #987](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/987) proposing to improve documentation regarding this use case.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like they closed your ticket already.  But the solution/thread they cite doesn't fix the issue either.  So there is no way (even using column data) to apply `data-*` and the DataTables API is there?

Comment: @shanabus, use the solution I recommend in the answer.